# Qualcomm Atheros 8151 ethernet seems broken with kernel 5.4 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, ethernet, atheros

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 19.10 to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and it seems that the upgraded kernel has broken the ethernet. The previous kernel (5.3.0-53-generic) is still able to be booted from, and seems to fix any issues with ethernet. My PC uses a Gigabyte Z77x-UD3H (revision 1.0), with a Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 V2.0 Gigabit Ethernet adapter. `ip link` shows that the interface (enp5s0) is `UP` and the driver reported by `lshw -C network` is atl1c and version is `1.0.1.1-NAPI`, which is consistent between both kernels. On 5.4, pinging my network gateway (or any PC on my local network for that matter) just results in `network unreachable`. Any thoughts as to how I could fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the interface is up?

Comment: Yes, `ip link` shows the interface is up.

Comment: Have the same mainboard with Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 V2.0 , and ended up in the same situation after installing Nvidia drivers using `ubuntu-driver autoinstall` on 22.04. Kernel 5.4.0-54-generic got installed, but the Ath9k module is not loaded.

Comment: Did you find a solution? For me it works fine with the Kubuntu 20.04 Live USB, but doesn't even appear in `ip link` once Kubuntu is installed. USB tethering doesn't work either.